# count the total votes for each candidate (voting system) in visual basic using microsoft acces

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

so im doing an election app for my final project and im stuck on making the right query to count the total votes of each candidate that has previously registered by the admin..so this is my coding on that part :

```
`Using myCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(StudentId) AS NoVotes 
 FROM 
Student_Voting LEFT JOIN Sign_Up ON Student_Voting.CandidateNumber = 
Sign_Up.CandidateNumber", dbconn)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("CandidateNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value 
= CanComboBox.Text
        Using myReader As OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            If (myReader.Read() = True) Then
                NovTextBox.Text = (myReader("NoVotes"))

            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

`
The above code results in only showing the total number of student who have voted but not the specific voters for each candidate..

NoVotes is a column to store the total count of each candidate temporarily and display the votes on the NovTextBox..and since the candidates are determined by the admin so the total candidates is not fixed.

**i would like to get the total voters for each candidate that have registered according to another table which is the Sign_Up table and display it on NovTextBox**

so if anyone could help, i would really appreciate it and of course sorry for any dumb mistakes..im really new at programming..also much thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Given what you have posted it looks Like your sql query is giving you what you asked for:  It seems you are asking to count the votes each candidate gets including candidates who get no votes (the left join)so this sql with some possible name tweeks might be what you are looking for:

SELECT Student_Voting.CandidateNumber, Count(Sign_Up.CandidateNumber) AS NoVotes
FROM Student_Voting LEFT JOIN Sign_Up ON Student_Voting.CandidateNumber = Sign_Up.CandidateNumber
GROUP BY Student_Voting.CandidateNumber;

I generated my sql using the designer.  It looked like:

[image]